# how to assign value in scala conditionally in template of play2.1

Tags: templates, playframework

I am doing some conditional coding in scala template.
just tell me how to write following java logic into scala.html template.

```
String temp = "";
 if(!cityName.equals(temp)){
         temp=cityName;
    }
 else{
        //do something.. 
     }
```

Comment: Your question is unclear, improve it, if you wanna get any sensible response.

Comment: @biesior: I have updated the post ....Pls have a look...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scala views allows you to define some variables with [`@defining` block](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.1/JavaTemplates) (see Reausable values), however it doesn't allow you to `re-assignate` it, so your pseudocode won't work as expected.

In such case you need to write custom getter in your model, which will return a valid value, instead doing it with temporary values in the views. You can also access any static Java method which will process your incoming string according to some conditions.

I must to say, that I have no idea what exactly you want to achieve, however *I think*, that can be solved with solutions proposed above.

Comment: I may be wrong, but personally I don't think so... first view shouldn't be used for advanced logic from its definition, second you can always use workaround with static methods/getters.